# Got this error 26 - error locating server/instance specified in client machine

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, remote-connection

My application works fine in my pc but not working in clients . I am tired of googling. Please anyone help me :(
I made following changes in my computer-
1.Remote access is stared
2.Sqlbrowser is started and running
3.tcp 1433 and udp 1433 exception added to windows firewall
4.tcp/ip-- IPALL port-1433

Comment: You need UDP port **1434** firewall exception for SQL Server Browser.

Comment: So are you attempting to execute a SQL command in SQL Server Management Studio on a client machine, or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: tried that too still same :( any other reason or solutions plz

Comment: Try going to your database instance in SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, and then open Management -> SQL Server Logs.  What do your logs tell you?

Comment: @Roger I am newbie to visual studio and sql server.I made an application using vs2010 and sql server database. It works fine in my computer but in client machine shows error 26. ....

Comment: What if you try turning your firewall off completely (just to test) on your client machine and database server machine?

Comment: @roger i have tried turning off firewall and about logs can you be more specific where can i get it i am newbie so cant find it exactly where it is i have seen Event logs>> and there are many of the kind which one i should be looking exactly

Comment: Sdp,  here is a screen shot of the SQL Server logs:

http://postimg.org/image/y66uqg4s1/

What do these say? Do you have SQL Server Management Studio installed on your client machine? You would need to install SQL Server Express with Advanced Services to get the management studio: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25174